# Issues with CFQUERY scope

Tags: scope, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

As far as I know

`<cfquery name="groups">`

is equivalent to

`<cfquery name="VARIABLES.groups">`

In my project, in different parts (inside different functions) there is a cfquery with the same names.

When there are a lot of requests, I started getting strange responses from REST API (Coldfusion) where there were different datasets.

Through experiments, I realized that if I declare a local variable before calling cfquery, this will solve the problem, since the answer will be written exactly to the function variable, and not to the global variable.

`<cfset var groups = {} />`
`<cfquery name="groups">`

This option works correctly in all test cases.

**My question is**: is it correct to declare a local variable for cfquery inside a function, or are there other approaches to avoid my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use ( when in a function ):

```html
<cfset var groups = {} /> 
<cfquery name="groups">

or

<cfquery name="local.groups">
```

You can also use the local scope when inside functions.  Without the use of var you're effectively making a global variable.  Using either var or local inside a function will protect you again over writing the variable outside the function.

Comment: This answer suggests that one should use the `var` keyword outside functions as well.  I don't agree.

Comment: The answer explicitly says "either var or local inside a function".  The question also specifically talked about inside a function.  Though I have made that more clear.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if `var` / `local` scoping of local cfquery names in functions is news to the OP, then also remember to apply the same discipline to other similarly tag-declared variables, like cfloop `index` variables, cfquery `result` and cfhttp `result` variables, and cfsavecontent variable names.